# My UI thread is blocked when await Dispatcher.BeginInvoke... (using WPF and WCF)

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, wcf, tap

I have a WPF window that creates and starts a timer in its constructor. The timer elapsed event triggers a method (SyncPTUpdate) which uses BeginInvoke to place a call to another method (PTProgressUpdateInThread) onto the Window's thread. This then calls a WCF call asynchronously (using the TAP pattern, auto-generated by VS 2013).

When I make the WCF call artificially long in duration (using thread.sleep in the server component), the UI of my WPF application freezes. Not initially, but after a few seconds have gone by.

Where am I going wrong?

```
public delegate void PTProgressDelegate();

// this method is called from a periodically firing timer (System.Timers)
private async void SyncPTUpdate(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    await this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, new PTProgressDelegate(PTProgressUpdateInThread));
}

private async void PTProgressUpdateInThread()
{
    PTMapFieldClient = new FieldClient();
    ServiceField.BlokPTProgress PTProgressFromServer = await PTMapFieldClient.GetPTProgressAsync(variousparametershere);
    PTMapFieldClient.Close();

    // now use the results of the WCF call to update the Window UI
    //...
}
```

Comment: BTW, use the `System.Action` delegate.

Comment: Why are you running on the UI thread at all?

Comment: You mean why am I running the timer on the Window thread? Good point, only because I am from a single-threaded culture and only slowly getting to grips with multi-threading. I thought a new timer spawned a new thread anyway?

Comment: You could use a `System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer` if you want your timer to fire on the main thread.

Comment: It sounds like the UI freezing may be caused by your comments. `// now use the results of the WCF call to update the Window UI`

Comment: Create a proper ViewModel which uses `Application.Current.BeginInvoke()` in order to `NotifyPropertChanged()` and all your problems will magically disappear.

Comment: @StephenCleary Good idea, but I know the freezing is not caused there because it only happens when I put a thread.sleep in my wcf code on the server, not in the client code above.

Comment: @HighCore Thanks, don't know what this is, but will investigate.

Comment: @FalconRime: Try replacing the call to your service with a `Task.Delay` and creating a reproducible test case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Dispatcher.BeginInvoke()` is often presented as a way to do things async, with the benefit of not having to create/involve another thread.

But that means it is only beneficial for small, lightweight jobs. Best thing here is to push the call(s) to PTProgressUpdateInThread() to the ThreadPool. Or yuse a threaded Timer.
You're not using the results after `await` anyway.

Comment: Thanks, will take a look at pushing a job onto the ThreadPool. Have updated my code to show that the results of the await is used to update the Window UI (hence needing it on the Window thread I assume).

Comment: Your solution worked well for me, thank you. I eventually implemented this, to get the workload onto a different thread.
    Thread MyNewThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() =>
                    {
        this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => { PTProgressUpdateInThread(PTProgress); })); // push the received data on to the UI thread
                    }
                    ));
    MyNewThread.Start();